# Find the largest sum of 3 consecutive digits from number

Tags: c, encoding

I have a task to write the C program that finds the largest sum of 3 consecutive digits in numbers. I wrote it, but I have trouble: the program seems to work fine, but instead of correct answer it types some strange numbers.
For example, if input is "560315", the response is "155". However, if I type "560415" the answer is still "155" and if I type "561315" the response changes to "156". Is it a problem with encoding?
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int isempt(int a) {
if ((a==' ')||(a=='\n')||(a=='\t')) {
    return 1;
}
else return 0;
}

main() {
int a, b, c, d, e, i, maxsum;
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
d = 0;
maxsum = 0;
i = 0;
int counter = 0; //the variables "numsearch" and "inside" indicate whether program is in the number or outside it
int numsearch = 1; 
int inside = 0;
while ((i = getchar())!=EOF) {
    if (numsearch==1) {
        if (isempt(i)==0) {
            numsearch = 0;
            inside = 1;
            a = i;
            counter++;
        }
        }
    else if ((isempt(i)==0)&&(inside==1)) {
            if (counter == 1) {
                b = i;
                counter++;
            }
            else if (counter == 2) {
                c = i;
                counter++;
            }
            else if (counter == 3) {
                d = i;
                maxsum = a+b+c;
                if ((b+c+d) > maxsum) {
                    maxsum =( b+c+d);
                }
                a =b;
                b = c;
                c = d;
                counter++;
            }
            else if (counter == 4) {
                d = i;
                if ((b+c+d)>maxsum) {
                    maxsum = b+c+d;
                }
                a=b;
                b=c;
                c=d;
            }

            }
        else if ((counter>=3)&&(isempt(i)==1)) {
                printf("\n%d\n", maxsum );
                counter = 0;
                numsearch = 1;
                inside = 0;
                a = 0;
                b = 0;
                c = 0;
                d = 0;
            }
            else {
                counter = 0;
                numsearch = 1;
                inside = 0;
                a = 0;
                b = 0;
                c = 0;
                d = 0;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's meant to find the 3 largest digits and then sum them? so 560315 should produce 16?

Comment: You're calculating with ASCII character values, not with numerical digits!!

Comment: @TomTanner No I believe the answer should be 11, it's the sum of 560

Comment: Not just 3 largest digits, but the largest sum of 3 consecutive digits

Comment: @g-makulik Thank you, that's exactly what I expected. But how do I calculate it with numbers instead of ASCII values?

Comment: You could use atoi() or bit-shift integer promotion.

Comment: @Alexei Besides @JonahNelson's suggestion, you could also simply subtract the ASCII value's offset (i.e. `int('0')`), as soon you're sure you have a numeric digit character.

Comment: @Alexei You can consult an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to check which numerical ranges you'll need to ensure digit characters.

Comment: @Alexei Ah, sorry I've overseen your question asks for [tag:c], please use `(int)'0'` instead of `int('0')` then (the latter is [tag:c++] syntax).

Comment: Interesting way of doing this. I would have used an array of 3 `int` and a rotating modulo index for the next value. [See it live](http://ideone.com/6OwMuZ)

Answer (score 4):

to solve this problem ,you can subtract `48` from `i` every time you use value of variable `i` to assign it to the variables of your algorithm : `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` , in this case the answer to your example 560316 will be 11 ,and I believe it's the largest sum of 3 consecutive digits, That will work because `48` is the ascii code of the digit 0 ,49 is for the digit 1 and so on, so your code should be like this :

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        int isempt(int a) {
        if ((a==' ')||(a=='\n')||(a=='\t')) {
            return 1;
        }
        else return 0;
        }

        void main() {
        int a, b, c, d, e, i, maxsum;
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
        d = 0;
        maxsum = 0;
        i = 0;
        int counter = 0; //the variables "numsearch" and "inside" indicate whether program is in the number or outside it
        int numsearch = 1; 
        int inside = 0;
        while ((i = getchar())!=EOF) {
            if (numsearch==1) {
                if (isempt(i)==0) {
                    numsearch = 0;
                    inside = 1;
                    a = i - '0';
                    counter++;
                }
                }
            else if ((isempt(i)==0)&&(inside==1)) {
                    if (counter == 1) {
                        b = i - '0' ;
                        counter++;
                    }
                    else if (counter == 2) {
                        c = i - '0';
                        counter++;
                    }
                    else if (counter == 3) {
                        d = i - '0';
                        maxsum = a+b+c;
                        if ((b+c+d) > maxsum) {
                            maxsum =( b+c+d);
                        }
                        a =b;
                        b = c;
                        c = d;
                        counter++;
                    }
                    else if (counter == 4) {
                        d = i - '0' ;
                        if ((b+c+d)>maxsum) {
                            maxsum = b+c+d;
                        }
                        a=b;
                        b=c;
                        c=d;
                    }

                    }
                else if ((counter>=3)&&(isempt(i)==1)) {
                        printf("\n%d\n", maxsum );
                        counter = 0;
                        numsearch = 1;
                        inside = 0;
                        a = 0;
                        b = 0;
                        c = 0;
                        d = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        counter = 0;
                        numsearch = 1;
                        inside = 0;
                        a = 0;
                        b = 0;
                        c = 0;
                        d = 0;

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem really was that the program calculated ASCII codes of numbers! But it's really strange, all programs I wrote before calculated numbers correctly and if I wanted to see ASCII code I just put it in single quotes.

Comment: @Alexei But here in this program your assigning a char to an integer, it's clear that it is the ASCII code value that will be assigned instead of the value of the digit meant, I don't know about other cases where this will work like you mentioned in your previous programs, i haven't encountered one !

Comment: Instead of using a magic number (`48`), I'd recommend to use the offset for the 1st character directly: `int('0')`. This makes it much more readable what's going on.

Comment: @g-makulik yes you are right, it's really more readable , thanks for the advice

Comment: `'0'` is an `int`.  Cast is not needed.  Try `printf("%d\n", sizeof('0'));`

Answer (score 2):

You have so many nested conditionals that I think you may be confusing yourself. I believe it would be easier to make an array of integers, and at each index of the array, initialize to zero. Then add the digit indicated by the index plus one (first digit to 0th index, second digit to 1st index, etc) to that index and the two previous indices (if they exist, you'll have to bounds check). Then just find and print the largest number in the array.

Comment: I admit that program looks confusing (with switch condition and arrays it would look better), but the problem is wrong output. It's all about how variables "maxsum" and "a,b,c,d" behave.

Comment: I believe that you're not printing the sum, but rather what looks to be an oddly sorted list of integers where the largest integer gets overwritten by the smallest integer (happens frequently with off-by-one errors in sort algorithms). The overreaching difficulty in reading the code was contributing to errors that you're not able to find easily is what I was getting at.

Answer (score 1):

@T-D has the main issue covered well: use `a = i - '0'` rather than `a = i`.  (in 4 places)
@Jonah Nelson does point out the nesting is a bit excessive.  A simplified version follows.
OP code does have trouble with text that is neither whitespace nor digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
  int ch;
  int index = 0;
  char history[2];
  int maxsum = -1;
  int sum = 0;  // running sum
  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (isdigit(ch)) {
      ch -= '0';  // Convert text code to `int` value.
      sum += ch;
      if (index >= 2) {
        if (sum > maxsum) {
          maxsum = sum;
        }
        sum -= history[0];
        history[0] = history[1];
        history[1] = ch;
      }
      else {
        history[index++] = ch;
      }
    }
    else {
      if (!isspace(ch)) {
        printf("Unexpected text '%c'\n", ch);
      }
      index = 0;
      sum = 0;
    }
  }
  printf("Maximum sum: %d\n", maxsum);
  return maxsum < 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a really simple program, you don't need to index into an array. Just remember the last 2 digits. Thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() 
{
    int ch;
    int count = 0;
    int first = 0;
    int second = 0;
    int sum = 0;  /* running sum */
    int max_sum = 0; /* max sum */
    while (ch = getchar(), ch != EOF) 
    {
        if (isdigit(ch))
        {
            ++count;
            ch -= '0';  /* Convert text code to `int` value. */
            sum += ch;
            if (sum > max_sum) 
            {
                max_sum = sum;
            }
            sum -= first;
            first = second;
            second = ch;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Ignored unexpected text '%c'\n", ch);
            /* Optionally reset first, second, sum and count to 0 */
        }
    }
    printf("Maximum sum: %d\n", max_sum);
    return count < 3; /* Didn't get enough characters */
}
```

Comment: Would not this score 18 on string `"99"` allowing a non 3 consecutive sequence to be counted as a potential `max_sum`?   I think you want `if ((count >= 3) && (sum > max_sum)))`

Comment: That's what the `return count < 3' is for. it's not clear what is meant to happen if the input is too short or non-numeric. And how would you distinguish between '0', '00' and '000'?

Comment: OP's sample code has `isempt()` to use select whitespaces as delimiters of consecutive digit sequences.  OP code specifically tests for `max_sum` after 3 consecutive digits are found, reseting on whitespace.  I would distinguish between "00" and "000" with error return value of -1 (or a message) and a legit return value of 0.  Agree about some ambiguity in OP's post.